# Swift operator "is"

Tags: swift

According to the [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_500), checking type operator is "is".

I'm trying the bellows.

```
class BaseClass {
}

class SomeClass : BaseClass {
}

class OtherClass : BaseClass {
}
```

---

```
var s_ : SomeClass = SomeClass()

if(s_ is SomeClass) {
}


if(s_ is OtherClass) {
}
```

The compiler said `'is' test is always true` for the first if statement, and `'OtherClass' is not a subtype of 'SomeClass'`.

Why can't I compile this?

***ADDED***

This is the correct way to use `is`

```
var arr_ : [AnyObject] = Array<AnyObject>()
arr_.append(BaseClass())
arr_.append(SomeClass())
arr_.append(OtherClass())

for object in arr_  {
    if(object is SomeClass)
    {
        println("\(object) is SomeClass")
    }
    else
    {
        println("\(object) is not SomeClass")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you have with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the statements are true and make sense because `s_`, as declared, *must be* an object of SomeClass.

Thus, `_s is SomeClass` is always true, because it *must* be an object of SomeClass. And, `_s is OtherClass` is always false because OtherClass is *not* a subtype of SomeClass as stated. Since these are provable mistakes the compiler prohibits the usage as such.

Now, change the code to `var s_ : BaseClass = SomeClass()` and note the different results.

With this change the value of `s_` might *not* be an instance of SomeClass (as far as the compiler and type-system know), but it could be *any object that conforms to BaseClass*, including both SomeClass and OtherClass which are subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing makes perfect sense. It's akin to, using simple substitutions:

```
define shape
define square as subclass of shape
define circle as subclass of shape

s = square()
print (s is square) # yes, obviously.
print (s is circle) # no, not a chance.
```

Perhaps you meant that last one to be `s is shape` (or, in your case, `s_ is BaseClass`).